# Converting a SQLite flask app to a Postgres app for Heroku

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, flask, github, heroku

I built a Flask app with a SQLite database. Now, I want to actually upload the app for use. I uploaded to Github and connected the Github  repo to Heroku but realized that I can't use SQLite with Heroku because the database resets every hour. It seems like using the Heroku Postgres database is best, but I'm not sure how to convert my app. All of the tutorials for creating Postgres flask apps I could find are completely different from each other but equally confusing (either they assume I already have something built that I don't or a step is missing or a first step simply doesn't work). How should I even get started with this?

Comment: Are you using something like SQLAlchemy, or did you build your app using the `sqlite3` module directly?

Comment: i used sqlite3 directly

Comment: Then, unfortunately, you're going to have to rewrite your database code.